# Using MiKTeX 2.9 and amsmath, why do standard options in build setup not work?

Tags: pdftex, compiling

When setting up the build options, I accept the default options.
When using mode Latex>dvi the output is near perfect, but I understand pdf should be even better.
When using mode LateX>dvi>pdf the build stops before completion.
When using mode LateX>pdf output is fully generated, but page, text sizes and line thicknesses are all wrong.
I am using the latest Adobe Reader.
How can I find the optimum arrangement to use?

Comment: There are lots of editors around and it is quite unclear what your means with "latex>pdf". But beside this: probably pdflatex is the right choice for you but all the other variants  should work too if your code is correct.

Comment: latex>pdf is the first of about six profiles available, from which you later select one to use.  From what you say, I think my best approach is to strip the content down to a few lines - and then gradually replace the text.

Comment: There are lots of latex editors, if you don't say which one you use "6 profiles" is meaningless.

Comment: your question is completely impossible to understand.  You seem to be asking about the configuration in some unspecified editor, not actually asking about tex itself?

Comment: Sorry to be so vague...  I've reinstalled MiKTeX 2.9 and accepted all default setup parameters - including default text editors.  When building  Latex>DVI, I get an excellent result in all respects.  I need to understand please: what is the difference between taking the DVI result outside of MiKTeX and converting it to pdf externally and, alternatively, persisting in trying to get MiKTeX to do the complete job internally using the Latex>DVI>pdf profile that MiKTeX offers?  All my graphics files are included with both eps and pdf extensions.